# how to shine the background color (glossy)in htlml and css

Tags: html, css, angular, css3pie

I have created the dashboard using angular and I have placed the background color of balck and greay usig linear-gradient,but it is not looking good.

**I want to make my dashboard background as shiny with black color.**

**dashboard.component.css**

```
#bgcolor {
  background-color:lightgray; 
 background-image: linear-gradient( black , grey); 
}
```

Can anyone help me how to shine the background color with balck

Comment: to get a shine on black background , you have to use a lighter color like white in the gradient

Comment: This may helps you https://www.eggradients.com/category/black-gradient

Comment: Thanks@Rayees AC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body{
height:100vh;
}
.radial-gradient {

    background-repeat:no-repeat;

background-size: 100% 100%;
background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-corner at 40px 40px,
      #111 20%, #333 100%,#ddd 100%);
}
.text-glow{
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc,
               0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
               0 3px 0 #bbb,
               0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,
               0 5px 0 #aaa,
               0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
               0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
               0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
               0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
               0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
               0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
               0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
.t2{

  color: white;
   text-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff, 0 0 3px #ff4da6, 0 0 4px #ff4da6, 0 0 5px #ff4da6, 0 0 6px #ff4da6, 0 0 7px #ff4da6, 0 0 8px #ff4da6;
}
```

```html
<body class="radial-gradient">
<center>
 <h1 class="text-glow">Is this Okay ? </h1>
 <h1 class="t2">ddind</h2>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks@Sandrin Joy, working fine for me and I want to make the white text color  with shiny color can you help me is it possible to make the white text as shiny(glossy effect).

Comment: yea we can do it !